# Regex: replace relative image urls in markdown string with Javascript/Node

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown

I currently have some markdown posts that I'm pulling from a github repo. All of the images in the posts are relatively linked, and I need to prepend the relative URLs with a CDN link globally.

Current:
`[000](images/000.png)`

Desired:

```
[000](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gaurangrshah/site-cms@main/images/000.png)
```

I attempted a few ways, but can't seem to be able to target the "image" for some reason:

post.matter.content = post?.matter?.content.replace(
"images.*/g",
`${imageBase}/images`
);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String.replace accepts either a string or a regular expression as the first argument.  You are passing a string, but you want it to be a regular expression.  So just change the first parameter of replace as follows:

```js
const post = {
  matter: {
    content: `[000](images/000.png)`
  }
};

const imageBase = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gaurangrshah/site-cms@main";

post.matter.content = post?.matter?.content.replace(
  /images/g,
  `${imageBase}/images`
);

console.log(post.matter.content);
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across a non-regex solution that I'm sharing here for posterity (aka my future self).

```js
post.matter.content = post?.matter?.content.replaceAll('images', `${imageBase}/images`);
```